# Does database mirroring replicate the time stamp for database backups?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

We use *Quest Spotlight* for database server monitoring.  Depending on when SQL server decides to fail over automatically, we will get an alert stating that a database has not been backed up in over three days (the factory default) if that server has not been primary in over 72 hours.

My suspicion is that SQL Server does NOT replicate this data, but I wanted to hear from the community since a quick Google search didn't provide anything.  Plus, I am travelling and do not have time to test and I need to provide a fairly immediate response.

Comment: It really depends on *how* the monitoring software is deciding this. If it's looking in MSDB, then yes @kin is correct. However the timestamp for the actual database backup (full and log) should be stamped in the database boot page which should be updated on the mirror.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backup data is stored in `msdb`, which is a system database and cannot be part of mirroring or AlwaysON.

So the software should be smart enough to check or implement a custom solution using PowerShell or linked server that will tell if a database is lacking a recent backup.